# Why does removing 'self' cause an error when my input is valid?

Tags: python, class, self

I have a relatively basic question about classes and 'self', and although I know what they are used for after researching- I still don't quite understand some of the practical implementations.

My questions:

1. I am getting 'self' is not defined for the last line of code. Why is this?
2. I have seen in instances where within the function of post-order_traversal_iterative that I would do self.root, but in other cases it is just root.
   I know the purpose of class is so that we can reference variables and other things within the same class but in different functions, and that is where we would use self.root for example- is this right?
3. Considering 2. I don't believe we need 'self' here at all. But when I take all the self's out, I get an unexpected argument for my input [1,None,2,3]

   ```
    class Treenode:
        def __init__(self,val=0, left=None, right=None):
            self.val = val
            self.left = left
            self.right = right

    class Solution:
        def post_order_traversal_iterative(self,root):
            stack = [root]
            output = []
            if not root:
                return []
            while stack:
                curr = stack.pop()
                output.append(curr.val)
                if curr.right:
                    stack.append(curr.left)
                if curr.left:
                    stack.append(curr.right)
            return output

    x = Solution()
    print(x.post_order_traversal_iterative(self,[1, None, 2, 3]))
   ```

Comment: Question, is `root` in the function supposed to be a `Treenode` rather than a list?

Comment: doctor, I don't quite understand. In the code above, root is supposed to be a Treenode. specifically the first/top node of the tree

Comment: I mean call `print(x.post_order_traversal_iterative(Treenode(1, None, 2, 3))` because `[1, None, 2, 3]` is a list not a `Treenode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention `self` outside the class. Python uses this for you in the background in instance methods.

You made an `x`, which allows you to call the instance method like this `x.post_order_traversal_iterative([1, None, 2, 3])`

(Think of this like `Solution.post_order_traversal_iterative(x, [1, None, 2, 3]`)

Comment: Thanks Doctor- in what instance would I need to use self? For all code, is it possible to avoid using it?

Comment: Inside the class when you want to refer to instance variables